# Datatable not working proper in angular html view

Tags: angular

I am trying to load data table but filters are not working proper

```html
            <table class="datatable-init nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist" data-auto-responsive="ture">
                            <thead>
                              <tr class="nk-tb-item nk-tb-head">
                                <th class="nk-tb-col"><span class="sub-text">{{'Name' | translate}}</span></th>
                                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md"><span class="sub-text">{{'Contact No' | translate}}</span></th>
                                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg"><span class="sub-text">{{'Address' | translate}}</span></th>
                                <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md"><span class="sub-text">{{'Status' | translate}}</span></th>
                                <th class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools text-right">
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr class="nk-tb-item" *ngFor="let property of propertiesList.data">
                                <td class="nk-tb-col">
                                  <div class="user-card">
                                    <div class="user-avatar {{commonHelper.getThumbnailBG(property.prop_name)}} d-none d-sm-flex">
                                      <span>{{commonHelper.getNameThumbnail(property.prop_name)}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="user-info">
                                      <span class="tb-lead">{{property.prop_name}} <span class="dot dot-success d-md-none ml-1"></span></span>
                                      <span>{{property.prop_contact_email}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                                  <span>{{property.prop_contact_no}}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                                  <span>{{property.prop_address_1 +","+ property.prop_address_2 +"-"+property.prop_pincode}}</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                                  <span class="tb-status text-success" *ngIf="property.prop_is_active == 1">Active</span>
                                  <span class="tb-status text-danger" *ngIf="property.prop_is_active == 0">Inactive</span>
                                </td>
                                <td class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools">
                                  <ul class="nk-tb-actions gx-1">
                                      <div class="drodown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-icon btn-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown"><em class="icon ni ni-more-h"></em></a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                          <ul class="link-list-opt no-bdr">
                                            <li><a href="admin/viewProperty/{{property.prop_id}}"><em class="icon ni ni-eye"></em><span>{{'View Details' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="admin/addProperty/{{property.prop_id}}"><em class="icon ni ni-edit"></em><span>{{'Edit Details' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="deleteProperty(property.prop_id)"><em class="icon ni ni-delete"></em><span>{{'Delete' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngIf="property.prop_is_active == 1" (click)="changePropertyStatus(0, property.prop_id)"><em class="icon ni ni-property-remove"></em><span>{{'Deactivate' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" *ngIf="property.prop_is_active == 0" (click)="changePropertyStatus(1, property.prop_id)"><em class="icon ni ni-property-add"></em><span>{{'Activate' | translate}}</span></a></li>
                                          </ul>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </ul>
                                </td>
                              </tr><!-- .nk-tb-item  -->
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
```

It show no data available and filter not working

[image]

```
        import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
        import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
        import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
        import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        import { AppConstants } from '../../app-config/app-constants';
        import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';
        import { DbTables } from '../../app-config/db-tables';
        import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
        import { CommonHelper } from '../../app-config/common-helper';
        import { GridLayout, Image, PlainGalleryConfig, PlainGalleryStrategy } from '@ks89/angular-modal-gallery';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-properties',
          templateUrl: './properties.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./properties.component.css']
        })
        export class PropertiesComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor(public translate: TranslateService,
                      public route: Router,
                      private commonService: CommonService,
                      public appConst: AppConstants,
                      public commonHelper: CommonHelper
          ) {
              translate.setDefaultLang("en");
          }
          propertiesList: any = {numRows: 0, data:[]};
          ngOnInit(): void {
              this.translate.use(localStorage.getItem("lang"));
              this.fetchProperties();
          }
          fetchProperties () {
              this.commonService.fetchPropertyService({dbname: this.appConst.DATABASE}).subscribe(
                  Response => {
                      const apiResponse: any = Response;
                      console.log("fetchProperties :", apiResponse);
                      this.propertiesList.numRows = apiResponse.numRows;
                      this.propertiesList.data = apiResponse.data;
                  },
                  Error => {
                      console.log("fetchProperties Error:", Error);
                  }
              );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps for using Datatable in Angular are pretty easy.

Step 1 : Install jQuery `npm i jquery`.

Step 2 : Include jQuery in you app, in either angular.json or index.html.

Step 3 : Install Datatable

```
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

Step 4 : Include it in you **angular.json**

Your final angular.json should look like this.

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
            ],
```

Step 5 : Import Datatable Modules into you Module.

Step 6 : Create **dtTrigger** and **dtOptions** in your component.ts.

```
    dtOptions: any = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      lengthMenu: [
        [10, 15, 25, -1],
        [10, 15, 25, 'All']
      ],
      destroy: true,
      retrive: true,
      language: {
        search: '_INPUT_',
        searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
      },
      dom: "<'row' <'col-md-8'l> <'col-md-2'B> <'col-md-2' f> >r t i p"
     };
    dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Step 7 : Add 3 new properties **datatable**, **dtTrigger** and **dtOptions** in your table in html of that component.

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
```

Step 8 :  Finally call **dtTrigger.next()** whenever you push data into thearray from which the table is getting the data.
for example :

```
this.allUsers = res.data;  
this.dtTrigger.next();
```